# How to split everything after - (dash) using MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, split

I need to split data within a cell separated by `-` (dash) and put into separate columns. The problem I am having is there may be more than one `-`.

So using the table below with the original data coming from `sic_orig`, I need to put everything before the first `-` in `sic_num` and everything after the first `-` in `sic_desc`. I'm sure this is really easy, but I can't seem to find anything clear on this.

This is what my table should look like with `sic_orig` being the source and `sic_num` and `sic_desc` being data pulled from `sic_orig`:

```
              sic_orig                |  sic_num  |        sic_desc
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
  509406 - Jewelers-Wholesale         |   509406  |  Jewelers-Wholesale
--------------------------------------|-----------|------------------------
  506324 - Burglar Alarm Systems      |   506324  |  Burglar Alarm Systems
--------------------------------------|-----------|------------------------
  502317 - Picture Frames-Wholesale   |   502317  |  Picture Frames-Wholesale
```

This code works, but only works right if there are two `-`'s and some cells may have 1, 2 or 3 `-`'s

```
 UPDATE test_tbl_1 
    SET sic_num = SUBSTRING_INDEX(`sic_orig`, '-', 1),
        sic_desc = SUBSTRING_INDEX(`sic_orig`, '-', -2);
```

How do I split everything before first `-` and everything after first `-`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a combination of SUBSTR() and LOCATE() function to help you slice the string:

```
UPDATE test_tbl_1 
SET sic_num  = SUBSTR(sig_orig, 1, LOCATE('-', sig_orig) - 1),
    sic_desc = SUBSTR(sig_orig, LOCATE('-', sig_orig) +  1) ;
```

Click [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html) for MySQL string functions.

Comment: Note that if there are no dashes in the original string, the "before first dash" expression will return empty string, and the "after first dash" expression will return the original string. This might be desirable behavior, but it does differ from the behavior of other approaches.

Comment: @spencer7593, everything about the OP's post indicates the original string will contain at least 1 dash. Quoting the OP: "The problem I am having is there may be more than one -"

Comment: Yes, all of the example strings contain a dash. Yes, it seems like OP is expecting all of the values to contain at least one dash character. But it isn't stated that this is guaranteed. I'm not going to assume that it is. The expressions in this answer will work for strings that don't contain a dash, but I think that it's important to note the behavior... with these expressions, if there is no dash character in the original string, these behave as as if everything was "after the dash". I was just adding a note pointing that out.

Comment: @ChemistryBlob this did exactly what I needed it to do. Thanks

Comment: Cool! Glad I could help

Answer (score 2):

One method is to use the length of the first part and use that for `substr()`:

```
UPDATE test_tbl_1 
    SET sic_num = SUBSTRING_INDEX(`sic_og`, '-', 1),
        sic_desc = SUBSTR(sig_og, CHAR_LENGTH(SUBSTRING_INDEX(`sic_og`, '-', 1)) + 1) ;
```

Answer (score 1):

Another alternative is to get a count of the dashes in the string. We can get a count of the number of dash characters by doing a replacement of all dash characters with an empty string, and then subtracting the length from the length of the original string.

As a demonstration:

```
 SELECT `sic_orig`
      , CHAR_LENGTH(`sic_orig`)-CHAR_LENGTH(REPLACE(`sic_orig`,'-','')) AS cnt_dashes
   FROM ( SELECT  '509406 - Jewelers-Wholesale ' AS sic_orig
          UNION ALL SELECT '506324 - Burglar Alarm Systems'
          UNION ALL SELECT '502317 - Picture Frames-Wholesale'
          UNION ALL SELECT ' la di dah no dashes '
        ) t
```

returns:

```
sic_orig                               cnt_dashes  
-------------------------------------  ----------
509406 - Jewelers-Wholesale                     2
506324 - Burglar Alarm Systems                  1
502317 - Picture Frames-Wholesale               2
lots-of - -dashes- --everywhere-- --           10
 zero dashes                                    0
```

We can use the expression that returns the count of dashes as the third argument of SUBSTRING_INDEX, multiplying by negative 1 to get a a negative value...

```
 SELECT `sic_orig`
      , TRIM(
          SUBSTRING_INDEX(`sic_orig`,'-'
          , 1
          )
        ) AS before_first_dash
      , TRIM(
          SUBSTRING_INDEX(`sic_orig`,'-'
          , -1*(CHAR_LENGTH(`sic_orig`)-CHAR_LENGTH(REPLACE(`sic_orig`,'-','')))
          )
        ) AS after_first_dash
   FROM ( SELECT '509406 - Jewelers-Wholesale ' AS sic_orig
          UNION ALL SELECT '506324 - Burglar Alarm Systems'
          UNION ALL SELECT '502317 - Picture Frames-Wholesale'
          UNION ALL SELECT 'lots-of - -dashes- - -every-where-'
          UNION ALL SELECT ' zero dashes '
        ) t
```

returns:

```
sic_orig                            before_first_dash  after_first_dash          
---------------------------------   -----------------  ----------------------
509406 - Jewelers-Wholesale         509406             Jewelers-Wholesale
506324 - Burglar Alarm Systems      506324             Burglar Alarm Systems
502317 - Picture Frames-Wholesale   502317             Picture Frames-Wholesale
lots-of - -dashes- - -every-where-  lots               of - -dashes- - -every-where- 
 zero dashes                        zero dashes
```

The extra line breaks and formatting is intended to make deciphering the expressions easier, making sure parens balance, etc.

I *always* test my expressions with a SELECT statement first, before I put those expressions into an UPDATE statement.